# Editing a large dataset for SQLBulkCopy into a SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, csv

I have a VERY large (50 million+ records) dataset that I am importing from an old Interbase database into a new SQL Server database.

My current approach is:

1. acquire csv files from the Interbase database (done, used a program called "FBExport" I found somewhere online)
2. The schema of the old database doesn't match the new one (not under my control), so now I need to mass edit certain fields in order for them to work in the new database. This is the area I need help with
3. after editing to the correct schema, I am using `SqlBulkCopy` to copy the newly edited data set into the SQL Server database.

Part 3 works very quickly, diagnostics shows that importing 10,000 records at once is done almost instantly.

My current (slow) approach to part 2 is I just read the csv file line by line, and lookup the relevant information (ex. the csv file has an ID that is XXX########, whereas the new database has a separate column for each XXX and ########. ex2. the csv file references a model via a string, but the new database references via an ID in the model table) and then insert a new row into my local table, and then `SqlBulkCopy` after my local table gets large.

My question is: What would be the "best" approach (perfomance wise) for this data-editing step? I figure there is very likely a linq-type approach to this, would that perform better, and how would I go about doing that if it would?

Comment: This is a little broad as it will certainly invite conjecture as to the correct technology, and doesnt show any code or errors.  However, I think you are on the right path.  Another option could be to create a temp db with the same structure as the csv's and bulk copy up the files, then do your manipulation through sql.  This has its downsides as well though depending on your schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If step #3’s importing is very quick, I would be tempted to create a temporary database whose schema exactly matches the old database and import the records into it.  Then I’d look at adding additional columns to the temporary table where you need to split the XXX######## into XXX and ########.  You could then use SQL to split the source column into the two separate ones.  You could likewise use SQL to do whatever ID based lookups and updates you need to ensure the record relationships continue to be correct.

Once the data has been massaged into a format which is acceptable, you can insert the records into the final tables using IDENTITY_INSERT ON, excluding all legacy columns/information.

In my mind, the primary advantage of doing it within the temporary SQL DB is that at any time you can write queries to ensure that record relationships using the old key(s) are still correctly related to records using the new database’s auto generated keys.

This is of coursed based on me being more comfortable doing data transformations/validation in SQL than in C#.